# How can i track bash scripting error when installing packages

Tags: bash, runtime-error

I have written a script using bash script which will install some packages. If it can't install any packages then I want to track those packages, how can I do that?

```
#!/bin/bash

curlInstall(){
    echo ".........................curl installing.........................";
    update;
    sudo apt install curl;
    curl;
    echo ".........................curl install done.........................";

    echo "curl version check: ";
    curl --version;
}


gitInstall(){
    echo ".........................git installing.........................";
    sudo apt install git-all;
    echo ".........................git install done.........................";
}

vscode(){
    echo ".........................vscode installing.........................";

    sudo snap install --classic code

    echo ".........................vscode install done.........................";
}

commands[0]="curlInstall";
commands[1]="gitInstall";
commands[2]="vscode";


for item in ${commands[@]}
    do
        $item
    done
```

Comment: Catch $? value right after the calls to apt and snap. If they return something else than 0, than you got an error.

Comment: Your question is better suited to [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/tour) if you use Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

```sh
sudo apt install curl || echo 'Failed to install curl'
```

or

```sh
sudo apt install curl
if [ "$?" != 0 ]; then
    echo 'Failed to install curl'
fi
```

or

```sh
if ! sudo apt install curl; then
    echo 'Failed to install curl'
fi
```

You could also add `-e` parameter to bash, so that it stops script execution on error:

```sh
#!/bin/bash -e
```

Comment: Do not use `$?`. Just `if ! apt install curl; then`